# Number of ways to split 10 items into groups of 5 and 3 and 2

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 10 people, you want to split them into groups of 5 and 3 and 2. How many combinations are there?

I am wondering if the ordering in which you choose the groups matters. For example if I pick the group of 5 first would it be the same if I choose to pick the group of 3 first?

I'm guessing it is either $${10 \choose  5} {5 \choose  3} {2 \choose  2}$$ or 
$$\left[{10 \choose  5}+{5 \choose  3}+{2 \choose  2}\right]
+\left[{10 \choose  3}+{7 \choose  5}+{2 \choose  2}\right]
+\left[{10 \choose  2}+{8 \choose  5}+{3 \choose  3}\right]+
\left[{10 \choose  5}+{5 \choose  2}+{3 \choose  3}\right]+
\left[{10 \choose  3}+{7 \choose  2}+{5 \choose  5}\right]+
\left[{10 \choose  2}+{8 \choose  3}+{5 \choose  5}\right]$$

Comment: The first is fine. If you prefer you can use $\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: Does it over count?

Comment: By it is fine I meant it is correct, in particular it does not overcount. You do have to be careful. If it were groups of 4-3-3 then $\binom{10}{4}\binom{6}{3}$ overcounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the order:
$$
\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2}=\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{5}\binom{2}{2}=\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}=\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{5}\binom{3}{3}=\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{5}=\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{5}
$$
The trick is to convince yourself of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its basically like this.
You have 10 people and first you want to create a group of 5, the order of those 5 doesn't matter. There are 10nCr5 ways of doing it.

Next you have 5 people left and you want to create a group of 3, there are 5nCr3 ways of doing it.

Finally you are left with 2 people and want to create a group of 2, there are 2nCr2 ways of doing this.